# Hibernate update does suddenly not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am facing a strange problem. Without any change, hibernate does not do anything if I call update for a specific entity type.
There are not error/debug messages. I enabled hibernate.show_sql in the config and cannot see an update query, only queries for select and insert are shown.

Has anyone a clue how to solve, or at least debug the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the update is executed inside a transaction; my guess is it is not.

> **Transactions**
> Transactions also group
> data access operations, in fact, every
> SQL statement, be it queries or DML,
> has to execute inside a database
> transaction. There can be no
> communication with a database outside
> of a database transaction. (Note that
> there are such things as read-only
> transactions, that can be used to
> improve cleanup time in a database
> engine if it is not smart enough to
> optimize its own operations.)
>
> The
> right approach is to define clear
> transaction boundaries in your
> application by beginning and
> committing transactions either
> programmatically, or if you have the
> machinery to do this, declaratively
> (e.g. on service/command methods). If
> an exception occurs the transaction
> has to be rolled back (or
> declaratively, is rolled back).

[Read more](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions)

Working with transactions is easier if you use [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).

Comment: +1 I found the easiest way to find out if it's in a transaction (at least with Spring) is to debug the application and see the stack. If the transactional proxy is missing, then I forgot to add the annotation at some point.

Comment: Erik didn't mention anything about using spring framework and I have to disagree with the statement 'The easiest way to work with transactions is using spring'. I would rather say it depends. If you are using full Java EE compilant container I would say that the easies way to use transactions would be to use container managed transactions with your EJB's where you don't have to worry to begin and commit the transaction as its done automatically by the container on the method level (unless you explicitly want to change it of course)